# How to list files in ftp directory older than 20 minutes using Perl?

Tags: perl, ftp

I have a code that list files through an ftp directory but I want to be able to only list files that are older than 20 minutes.

```
use Net::FTP;

#Global variables that i am not going to list down..

my $pattern = 'fi*';
my @remote_files;


my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host) or die "Error connecting to $host: $@";

$ftp->login($username,$password) or die "Login failed: ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->cwd($ftpdir) or die "Can't go to $ftpdir: ", $ftp->message;

print $ftp->pwd();

@remote_files = $ftp->ls($pattern);

foreach my $file (@remote_files){
   print "file: $file\n";
}

$ftp->quit or die "Error closing ftp connection: ", $ftp->message;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm i solved this on my own  i used

```
$ftp->mdtm($file);
```

to get the time for the file and compare it with the current time minus than 20 minutes.